# Android AIDE, logcat scrolling on runtime error

Tags: android, aide-ide

On every runtime error in AIDE (when the application crashes) the logcat window is displaying all messages again (even from the last days) which needs long time to scroll to the end to find out what's wrong. I don't want always clear the logcat list before i compile the project, but i did not find any setting to avoid this behavior. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: use command line for logcat. Don't use an IDE for logcat

Comment: If you want to observe logcat and having trouble with AIDE, you should just do it on your workstation.

Comment: @JoxTraex: the IDE is running on Android, i don't have a command line.

Comment: @Harshiv: most of the time i have only my phone with me :-)

Comment: another option would be to use remote logcat debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can have command line,use

- **Terminal IDE** if your device is running on android 4.x
  or lower,
- **Termux** if Lollipop+, 
  launch your app within one of these Terminal Emulators with `am` command:

  ```
  am start -a android.intent.action.Main -n com.your.package/.Ur_Main_Activity
  ```

And then use the `logcat` command to observe log, it will be a bit cumbersome though, use filters as you see fit. Enter ctrl+C to end Logcat dump. Hope this helps,

Comment: interesting approach. I think i will give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the apk with exact package and activity name must be installed before using this method. If you are debugging,  then make bash/sh script of above am command  and give it executable permission:  "chmod +x run.sh" and things will be a bit faster.

Comment: Ok, i will try this. Thanks!